Can't get ST_PointOnSurface return points as MVT from Polygons on PostGIS / Martin Tile Server
I'm trying to get points from my database and show them with the "value" columns.
My db has several Polygons in the GEOM caolumn.
But I only want to get as an MVt the ones that are being requested in the bounds.
This is the current function I built, but I can't make it work.
I'm sure that the polygons are there because I have one very similar function that shows me correctly the polygons on QGIS.
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_mvt_depths(
    z integer, x integer, y integer)
RETURNS bytea
AS $$

DECLARE
    result bytea;
BEGIN
    WITH
    bounds AS (
        SELECT ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y) AS geom
    ),
    mvtgeom AS (
        SELECT
            ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(ST_PointOnSurface(t.geom), 3857), bounds.geom) AS geom,
            t.value
        FROM public.bathymetries t, bounds
        WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 4326))
    )
    SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'depth')
    INTO result
    FROM mvtgeom;

    RETURN result;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
STABLE
PARALLEL SAFE;

